# Trying to create a simple password protection code for Rstudio

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, passwords

So I decided that I would attempt to create a very rudimentary password protection function that would run every time I opened Rstudio. After a couple of hours I came up with the following code

```
whoRU <- function()
    {
    password<- "mypassword"
    Henry<- "Henry"
    n <- readline(prompt="Who are you then? ")
    if(n== Henry){
            print(p<-readline(prompt= "If you are Henry, you must know the password? "))
            if(p== password){
                    (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))
            }
            else{
                    (print(p2<- readline(prompt="Dude, you suck! Shall we try that one again?")))
                     if( p2== password){
                             (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))     
                     }
                     else{
                             (print(p3<- readline(prompt= "Mate you are killing me! I am going to give you one more chance because I like you. What is the password?")))

                     }
                    if(p3== password){
                            (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))
                    }
                    else{
                            print("Dude you suck! No coding for you")

                            quit(save = "yes")

                    }

            }


    }
    else{
            print(ps<- readline(prompt= "Hello stranger, you are going to have to provide the password I'm afraid:"))
                    if(ps== password){
                            (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))
                    }
                    else{

                            (print(ps2<- readline(prompt="Dude, you suck! Shall we try that one again?")))
                            if( ps2== password){
                                    (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))     
                            }
                            else{
                                    (print(ps3<- readline(prompt= "Mate you are killing me! I am going to give you one more chance because I like you. What is the password?")))

                            }
                            if(ps3== password){
                                    (print("Welcome home, lets get coding!"))
                            }
                            else{
                                    print("Dude you suck! No coding for you")

                                    quit(save = "yes")


                            }
                    }



    }

             }
```

This code seems to work fairly well but I am open to suggestions as to how it can be improved. My main issue is a couple of very slight issues. Firstly once a user has typed in the password, the password is then printed to the console. i.e.

```
    If you are Henry, you must know the password? mypassword
[1] "mypassword"
```

which I would prefer not to happen. Secondly once the correct password has been entered the code seems to print the welcome message twice, which I dont want it to do.

```
Who are you then? Henry
If you are Henry, you must know the password? mypassword
[1] "mypassword"
[1] "Welcome home, lets get coding!"
[1] "Welcome home, lets get coding!"
```

now my thinking is that maybe it is running both iterations of the if loop (where Henry and p==password, and where any other name and ps==password) but I cant figure out how to rectify this so that it doesnt occur.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `print` around your `readline` calls since `readline` with `prompt` will print the prompt for you. That's what's causing your first issue. You have parentheses around the `print` for the welcome message. That's causing your second issue. But, what do you think this password script is protecting? Or, was it just an exercise to play with some functions?

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise? Anyone remotely familiar with R will know that they can just hit "Esc".

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply, it was mostly an exercise to play around with but I also live in a house where people aren't familiar with R, but are likely to mess around with my laptop, so attempting to protect it made sense.

Comment: Set a password for your laptop.

Comment: I have a password on my laptop already. As I said this was mostly an educational/fun exercise for me to do.

@hrbrmstr thank you for your help, your suggestions have resolved the issues.

Comment: This is a great example of code which belongs in thedailywtf.com . Once someone's got a running shell in your account, you're totally screwed. Putting impotent pseudo-passwords inside a script inside an application is less than worthless.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It was my understanding that stackoverflow was for getting answers to technical questions and maybe answering a few yourself. I did this as an exercise as I've already stated. I am still learning and figured this would be a good learning exercise. I am sorry you feel this code is worthless, it is certainly not worthless to me. I have learnt a great deal writing it and even more from the helpful people on this site. If my code offends you so much, please ignore my post and don't comment on it. You are not obliged to comment after all.

Comment: But your posted question assumes a situation which is not defensible.  SO is not about answering wrong things. It's about showing how to abandon dead ends (or mistakes) and moving on to useful methodologies.

Comment: Yes and I asked for a critique of the methodology (i.e. code), not the overall goal. Its like if you came looking for improvements in code related to your research and instead of helping you with the code, I just criticised your research. You weren't looking for a critique of your research when you posted about your code, and I would be a pretty poor SO member for providing one. 

besides, surely you as a programmer can't honestly be chastising me for trying something because it seemed like fun/a good learning exercise. I wasn't expecting to build a fort knox like security system in R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The printing issues are correctly identified by @hrbrmstr above - there are some code issues here you should probably target for readability (may I recommend the [Advanced R Programming Style Guide](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/style.html)? and you don't need expression syntax around print() calls)

I'm sort of struggling to see the point of this code; people could just, well, remove those lines. R is an inherently open language. If you're looking to actually provide some sort of security or encryption, you're probably best looking at [Hadley's package 'secure'](https://github.com/hadley/secure).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will certainly check out the "secure" package. This exercise was more for my own amusement and learning than anything else.

Comment: Fair enough! It's a fun little library :)